# Trajectory Analysis (SAS): Incorrect number of start values

Tags: sas

I am attempting a trajectory analysis in SAS (proc traj). 
Following instructions found online, I first begin by testing two quadratic models, then three, then four (i.e., order 2 2, order 2 2 2, order 2 2 2 2, order 2 2 2 2 2).

I determined that a three-group linear model is the best fit (order 1 1 1;)

I then wish to add time stable covariates with the risk command. As found online, I did this by adding the start parameters provided in the Log. 
At this point, I receive a notice: "Incorrect number of start values. There should be 10 start values based on the model specifications."). 
I understand that it's possible to delete some of the 12 parameter estimates provided - But how do I select which ones to remove? 
Thank you. 
Code:

```
proc traj data=followupyes outplot=op outstat=os out=of outest=oe itdetail;
id youthid;
title3 'linear 3-gp model ';
var pronoun_allpar1-pronoun_allpar3;
indep time1-time3;
model logit;
ngroups 3;
order 1 1 1;
weight wgt_00;
start 0.031547     0.499724     1.969017     0.859566    -1.236747     0.007471
    0.771878     0.495458     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000;
risk P00_45_1;
run;
%trajplot (OP, OS, "linear 3-gp model ", "Traj of Pronoun Support", "Pron Support", "Time");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are estimating a model with 3 linear trajectories, you will need 2 start values for each of your 3 groups.

See here for more info: https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/bjones/example.htm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm still a bit confused here - SAS states that I need 10 start values, but your response says that I need 6 start values. I'm trying to understand which start values to keep or remove. Can you explain which ones to remove? Thank you!